# Asymptotic polynomial growth of a matrix product

Tags: asymptotics, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

Consider the matrix
$$M_1=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$
Quite obviousely,
$$f(n)=M_1^n \left[\begin{matrix} a \\ b \end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} a+n b \\ b \end{matrix}\right]$$
exhibits polynomial (linear) growth. This is thanks to the non-diagonalizability of $M_1$.

Now consider
$$M_k=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ \exp(-k) & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$
$$g(n)=\prod_{k=1}^n M_k \left[\begin{matrix} a \\ b \end{matrix}\right]$$
While I do not have an explicit expression for $g(n)$, I am confident it is asymptotically linear.

A third example
$$M_k=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \exp(-k) & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & k \end{matrix}\right]$$
$$g(n)=\prod_{k=1}^n M_k \left[\begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right]$$
$$h(n)=\prod_{k=1}^n M_k \left[\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$
$g(n)$ is asymptotically linear, but $h(n)$ grows superpolynomially.

**Question**
I have a $3\times 3$ matrix $M_k$, and I have reason to believe that it exhibits asymptotically linear growth on some subspace (like $g(n)$) and superpolynomial growth (like $h(n)$) on another subspace. I seek a procedure to find the subspace in which it exhibits asymptotically linear growth.

Comment: Is that so? The Jordan normal form of 
$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ \exp(-k) & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$ is $$\left[\begin{matrix} 1+\exp(-k/2) & 0 \\ 0 & 1-\exp(-k/2) \end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: Numerically, $$g(n)=\prod_{k=1}^n \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ \exp(-k) & 1 \end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix} a \\ b \end{matrix}\right]$$ grows asymptotically linearly for all $a,b$, despite having an eigenvalue of absolute value $>1$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question. I thought you were taking powers of $M_k$ as in the first example.

Comment: Maybe it is just a matter of writing the eigenvalues of $M_k$ as function of $k$, and picking the eigenvectors associated with the two eigenvalues whose absolute value is $\leq 1$ in the $k\rightarrow \infty$ limit...